# Ionic $http.post catch errors

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a submit function, which posts some data into a server and then the server returns a response. The function is working fine. I would like, though, to catch a couple of errors during the post process. For example, if there is no connectivity to the server, return an error to the user to inform him what's going on. instead of just pressing the button and do nothing. I know I can create a function to somehow ping the server and check if it's alive but that's not what I need. I would like to have a statement in the error function and catch most of the possible errors and output an explanation to the user.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  var link = 'http://app.example.com/api.php';

  $http.post(link, {
    username: $scope.data.username,
    password: $scope.data.password
   }).then(function(res) {
    $scope.response = res.data;
    $localStorage.token = res.data;
    console.log($localStorage.token);
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
   })
   .finally(function() {
    //do something
   });
 };
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. I would like to improve it, and do what is described in the question/

Comment: if I remember correctly, "then" takes two params. One a function for success and another for fail. In addition you can create an http interceptor that handles all of this crap.

Comment: Agree with @yBrodsky

Comment: As I understand correctly, you want to handle an error massage. Inside of your catch you can read a status of your error.
 If 
inline `error.status`
equals 500, one of the reasons can be that the server is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
  $http.post(link, {
    username: md5.createHash($scope.data.username),
    password: md5.createHash($scope.data.password),
   }).then(function(res) {
     //Success Scenario
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
    if (error.statusText == ""){
      $scope.response = "Unexpected error. Make sure WiFi is on."
      //When the device is not connected on the internet the response error is -1 (or any number) and the statusText is empty. So we caching that one as-well.
    }
    else {
      $scope.response = "Error - "+error.status + " ("+error.statusText+")";
      //else we display the error along with the status, for example error 500 Internal Server error.
    }
   })
   .finally(function() {
    //This function will always be called at the end. Take advantage of it      :)
   });
```

I hope it's gonna be useful for someone.